# Ghostscript - Layers and Transparency

Tags: pdf, pdfbox, ghostscript

I have a pdf which (it seems) has multiple layers. In the background is a form, and above is a layer with the handwritten signature, comments and so on. I think its scanned - I can't provide it because it is a trustworthy document.

Using Ghostscript 9.56.1 with the PDFA.ps and transparency.ps from the Page and the command:

```
                switches.Add("-dQUIET");
                switches.Add("-dSAFER");
                switches.Add("-dPDFA=1");
                switches.Add("-q");
                switches.Add("-dBATCH");
                switches.Add("-sPAPERSIZE=a4");
                switches.Add("-dNOPAUSE");
                switches.Add("-sColorConversionStrategy=UseDeviceIndependentColor");
                switches.Add("-sDEVICE=pdfwrite");
                switches.Add("-dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY");
                switches.Add($"--permit-file-read={iccPath}");
                switches.Add($"-sPDFAICCProfile={iccPath}");
                switches.Add("-dPDFACompatibilityPolicy=2");
                switches.Add("-dNOPROMPT");
                ....// ps files, input - output...
```

I have the problem that the transparency part of the hand-written layer is rendered white and so the background (in this case the form/text) is hidden. Is it somehow possible with java (e.g. pdfbox) or Ghostscript directly to flatten the layers, keeping the transparency of the top layer to avoid hiding the text in the bottom layer?

Comment: First question is why you are taking a perfectly valid PDF file and making a new one. If this is just to turn it into a PDF/A -1b file then you are going to lose the transparency anyway, because PDF/A-1 doesn't support transparency. You could, therefore, try one of the pdfimage devices instead of pdfwrite, which will render the content to an image and wrap that up as a PDF file. Of course, that relies on the rendering being correct, which is doubtful in this case.

Comment: You could also, of course, use -dNEWPDF=false, but that's only an interim solution as eventually the old interpreter will be going away.

Comment: Yes it's because of PDF/A-1 - so how could I test it for PDFA2 oder PDFA3 - I changed the parameter -dPDFA=1 to -dPDFA=2 but it changed nothing, so I think I need to adapt the PDFA.ps?

Comment: No pdfa_def.ps doesn't need changing. Since you appear to have uncovered a bug, or an unimplemented feature, there's really no way to help you. You need to find a file you can share. Particularly the PostScript transparency.